# Firebase Rules are not working. Returning data even when I set up rules in Firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I set up Firebase Functions to make calls to my Firestore. I'm using admin.auth() and returning data. I set up custom rules in the Firestore Rules section, but the Functions are not following the Rules i.e. when I use the URL in Postman, I shouldn't be getting the data because it doesn't fulfill "if read, write: if request.auth != null". How do I address this?

Here is my Firebase Function Code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
  const uid = req.body.uid;

  admin
    .auth()
    .getUser(uid)
    .then(user => {
      admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('discover')
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          res.send(
            snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
              const data = Object.assign({ doc_id: doc.id }, doc.data());
              return data;
            })
          );
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.send({ message: 'Something went wrong!', success: false });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send({ error: 'Something went wrong!', success: false });
    });
};
```

Firestore Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

      match /users/{users} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
      }
      match /discover/{discover} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
      }
      match /favorites/{favorite} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      }
    }

}
```

I shouldn't be able to get this data from Postman (Since I'm not authenticated) but I'm still getting the data. I don't want the data to be accessible if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Security rules don't apply when you access the database via the Admin SDK, or any other time you use a service account.  It doesn't matter at all that you're using postman (or any other HTTP client).  The thing actually doing the database access here is the Admin SDK.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any recommendations on how to read and write to Firestore without the Admin SDK?

Comment: Use the client libraries in the mobile app along with a user logged in with Firebase Authentication.  That's the only way `request.auth` will work.